# Vowel Symbols and Sounds

Tags: phonology, phonetics, phonemes

Are there any differences between vowel symbols and vowel sounds?

Do i need to use / / when writing IPA symbols?

Comment: Obviously there is a difference between symbols and sounds, because they are in different media; but I can't think that you don't understand that, so I think your question must mean something else. I wonder if you are asking about the difference between sounds (where the representation is usually put between [ and ]) and [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) (which are usually notated between / and /). IPA symbols are regularly used for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any differences between vowel symbols and vowel sounds?

Well, obviously there is a difference because the one is a symbol and the other is a sound, but as Colin Fine said in his comment, this is a bit too trivial so I'm not exactly sure what you mean.
The symbols (like IPA letters ʁ, ə, a, ...) are visual representations of the concept of a sound. When you write ə, then you use a visual symbol that refers to the class of all sounds that sound like the initial *a* in *above*.
The sounds themselves are what you hear, or sometimes an abstraction over all of these sounds (meaning that by "the sound" you sometimes do not refer to one utterance of the sound, but rather to the mental image of a sound with those properties that all instances of that sound share).

> Do I need to use / / when writing IPA symbols?

- When talking about **the symbols themselves**, they are written **in
  isolation** without any brackets (like I did above when I listed
  examples of IPA letters, thereby referring to the symbols themselves
  rather to the sounds they denote).
- When talking about **phones**, the symbols are enclosed in **square brackets [ ]**.
  A phone is an actual speech sound on the more concrete, physical level, i.e. the sound that is pronounced.
  You use **phonetic** representation when transcribing real speech into phonetic script or describing how a word is actually pronounced.
- When talking about **phonemes**, the symbols are enclosed by **slashes / /**.
  A phoneme is an abstraction of phones that are perceived as belonging to the same entity in a language, so it's the more linguistic and less physical aspect of the concept "sound". Phonemes are often described as "the smallest unit of language that makes a difference in meaning". For example, in English, /k/ and /t/ make a difference in meaning (as in *kite* /kaɪt/ vs. *light* /laɪt/) and a speaker would regard /t/ and /k/ as different sounds in their language, so /k/ and /t/ are different phonemes in English. On the other hand, for example in German, whether you pronounce an /ʁ/ as [r], [ʀ] or [ʁ] makes no difference in meaning and a speaker would perceive all of these sounds as an "r", so [r], [ʀ], [ʁ] all belong to the same phoneme /ʁ/.
  The **phonemic** representation is the abstract level which depicts more or less the mental image you have in your head rather than an actual pronounciation of these sounds. It's what you use when you e.g. describe the lexicon entry of a word with all of its properties (phnological form, lexical category, inflectional paradigm, ...)  or the input to a phonological rule.

As a rule of thumb, one may roughly say that phones/phonetic representation (-> sqare brackets [ ]) is "what comes out of your mouth" and phonemes/phonological representation (-> slashes / /)  is  "what is in your head".

Comment: Thank you for this. I Hope I can explain it well to my instructor

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use slashes for anything, unless you're making a claim or unless you are instructed to do so by someone else (e.g. an instructor or editor). Slashes conventionally mean "underlying", but can also mean "phonemic", so let context, intent and instructions be your guide.

The word "symbol" is unfortunate since it can mean "letter", or "mental unit". There can be a physical waveform of the word "cheese", but we don't have such things in our heads, what we have is something symbolic that stands for something else (the entire class of utterances 'cheese', for example). But it can also be used to refer to a letter, like *ö, ø, eu*, depending on the system of writing you are using. In IPA, the letter "ø" is used to stand for a broad range of physical sounds encountered in Norwegian, Swedish, Finnish, French, German and Cantonese (and other languages).

However, rarely does anyone say "He made the sound represented by the IPA letter 'ø'", instead we treat "sound", "letter" and "symbol" as interchangeable, unless there is confusion and you need to specifically talk of "letters" and "physical sounds".

Regarding social conventions for presenting letters, you have to follow the style sheet of the publication that you are looking at. There is a general rule that you should not put linguistic data in a text paragraph without some demarcation, so you can't talk about ɪ just like that. You have to set it off somehow, so you might say "the vowel [ɪ]" or "the vowel *ɪ* or "the vowel /ɪ/" or "the vowel **ɪ**". If you have a data display, bare data (letters) are okay and you see that all the time (although in some journals, e.g. NLLT, they still use bold for *all* linguistic data and symbols. You can use italics so that *ʃæŋk* is set off to look different from surrounding text (though nobody does that in displays).

Brackets can be used, but should not be used misleadingly. The problem is that [] is supposed to be used only for phonetic transcriptions, i.e the symbolic representation of actual speech, but many people use [] incorrectly and you end up with absurdities like "[nk] → [ŋk]" ([] means "is pronounced as" and that means that how it "is pronounced" doesn't change to something else). Slash brackets are likewise used to refer to an underlying representation (there is only one, for a given word), but it also can refer to a derived representation, basically the surface pronounced form but specifically limiting the kind of information included (omitting allophonic facts, like aspiration).

Complicating the matter even more, there are people who make an ontological distinction between "phonemes" and "allophones", so that the "phoneme" *p* in "spit" is a different thing from the "allophone" *p* in "spit", and this is reflected in writing "phoneme /p/" and "allophone [p]". But many people don't buy into that claim -- they are the same thing (although [p] vs. /p/ may indicate to the reader what kinds of facts about pronunciation you are leaving out). That is why you have to ask your instructor or editor what their rules are for use of brackets, slashes, not to mention italics and bold. There is still no conventional bracket for "non-underlying intermediate form".

Comment: Wihle I trust you in being way more expertised in phonetics and phonology than I am, I think that "you don't need slahes for anything" and "let instructions be your guide" is not very helpful for someone who is (understandably) confused about the two constrasting notations. Although I agree that the distinction is not always made consistently and sometimes can not be because the boundaries are vague, I think that it is important for a beginner to become sensitive to the difference between phonological vs phonetic concepts, or underlying vs surface representations ...

Comment: ...  (as far as one believes in this distinction, but general introductory textbooks usually do).